# Angular 4 Decorator unable to access class scope

Tags: angular, typescript, scope, real-time, decorator

I'm trying to write a decorator which will call a method after a given interval. The idea is to make a realtime data service without changing anything in the base service code.

So far I have been able to achieve the following:

Decorator code:

```
export const ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL = Symbol();

export function repeat(): MethodDecorator {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        // get the original method reference
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
        let timer;
        descriptor.value = (...args) => {
        //set a timer to call the method every 3 seconds
        //TODO: make the interval dynamic
            timer = setInterval( () =>  {
                originalMethod.apply(target, args);
            }, 3000);
        };
        target[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL] = target.ngOnDestroy;
        // Destroy timer on Component destroy
        target.ngOnDestroy = function () {
            this[ON_DESTROY_SYMBOL]();
            clearInterval(timer);
            console.log('Component destroy event successfully handled!');
        };
        return descriptor;
    };
}
```

And use it so:

```
@repeat()
myMethod() {
    console.log('Logging in console',new Date());
}
```

This works as expected. The method is repeated every 3 seconds and I can see the logs in console.

But when I try to use any service in the class, it fails with error

`Cannot read property 'someService' of undefined`

My goal is to be able to use it like so,

Component Code:

```
export class PlaygroundComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    //inject service
    constructor(private someService: SomeService){
    }

    @repeat()
    myMethod() {
        this.someService.fetchData().subscribe(res => //do something with data);
    }
}
```

Service Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

fetchData() {
    return this.http.get('https://data.com/json/')
}
```

I am not able to figure how to use the correct the scope in the decorator. Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the code where you inject the service?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: could you show the service itself?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
target.ngOnDestroy = function () {
```

should be

```
target.ngOnDestroy = () => {
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Still getting familiar with the new syntax. So bound to forget small things like this. ;)

Comment: You're not the only one. It's always the first thing I check when I see a new question ;-)